# Insert data into MS Access table via VBA inputbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to access and trying to insert dates into a table named "Data l Business Date" using the input box functionality. Below is my code but i keep getting syntax error with insert into statement.

```
Function BusinessDate()

Dim StrSQL As String
StrSQL = ("INSERT INTO Data l Business Date ([T_Date]) SELECT '" & InputBox("Enter todays date") & "';")
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL

End Function
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to
include error message


.

See [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You must validate and format the date value:

```vb
Function BusinessDate()

    Dim StrSQL As String
    Dim InputText As String
    Dim InputDate As Date
   
    InputText = InputBox("Enter todays date")
    If IsDate(InputText) Then
        InputDate = DateValue(InputText)
        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO [Data l Business Date] ([T_Date]) VALUES (#" & Format(InputDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);"
        CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In access you should use somedthing like

```
"INSERT INTO tblName (fldName) VALUES ( '" & InputBox("Enter todays date") & "' )"
```

Your function should look like

```
Function BusinessDate()

Dim StrSQL As String
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO tblName (fldName) VALUES ( '" & InputBox("Enter todays date") & "' )"
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL

End Function
```

Further reading [Insert Into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql)

PS If you have a space in the tablename, you need to use [ ...], i.e.

```
"INSERT INTO [tbl name] (fldName) VALUES ( '" & InputBox("Enter todays date") & "' )"
```

Comment: Thanks! I kept getting the same error message but when i change the table name it worked. Appreciate your help
Function BusinessDate()

Dim StrSQL As String

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Business_Date (T_Date) VALUES ( '" & InputBox("Enter todays date") & "' )"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


End Function